# Why am I getting the error 'string indices must be integers' in this line of code?

Tags: python, string, integer, indices

okay so i know this probably doesn't look very tidy, but on the line 'FinalMessage' I am getting the error 'string indices must be integers' and I need a little help putting it right and understanding why. Any help appreciated :)

```
StartBalance = input("Enter a Start Balance - £")

InterestRate = input("Enter Interest Rate - %")

StartBalance = float(StartBalance)
InterestRate = float(InterestRate)
InterestRate = InterestRate/100

TotalBalance = StartBalance

MonthList = []
InterestList = []

Months = 24

print("Month     Interest      Total Balance")
for Months in range(0,25):
 Interest = TotalBalance*InterestRate/12
 TotalBalance = TotalBalance + Interest

  if Months < 10:
     message = " %d         %6.2f          %6.2f" %(Months, Interest, 
TotalBalance)
  else:
   message = " %d        %6.2f          %6.2f" %(Months, Interest, 
TotalBalance)
print(message)
MonthList.append(Months)
InterestList.append(Interest)

EndOfInput = False

while EndOfInput == False:
  NumOfMonth = input("Enter Month to see Interest and Balance - ")
  FinalMessage = float(NumOfMonth[MonthList]), float(Interest[MonthList]), 
float(TotalBalance[MonthList])
  print(FinalMessage)

  Response = ""
  while Response != "Yes" and Response != "No": 
    Response = input("Would you like to see another Month? - ")
    if Response == "Yes":
     if Response != "Yes" and Response != "No":
       print("Invalid input, please enter Yes or No")

if Response == "No":
   EndOfInput = True

print("Thank you for using this program, Goodbye :)")
```

Comment: `float(NumOfMonth[MonthList])` should probably be something like `float(MonthList[int(numOfMonth)]`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `MonthList` as an index to the `NumOfMonth` string? Perhaps you meant to do that the *other way around*? You'd have to convert your `NumOfMonth` value to an integer first, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `MonthList` as (heh) a list here `MonthList = []` . Then you try to use it as an index here `NumOfMonth[MonthList]`, which predictably fails.

I assume you wanted the Xth month, which would translate into:

`MonthList[NumOfMonth]`

But then you also have a wrong indexation here `Interest[MonthList]` , which i again, assume , was meant to be `InterestList[NumOfMonth]`

EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, you'd have to convert NumOfMonth to an int first `NumOfMonth=int(NumOfMonth)`

Comment: I thought it would be (NumOfMonth[MonthList]) because I'm trying to get it to take the number that the user inputs (say, 4) and finds april in the table and then prints the month (4), interest gained, then the total balance.

Comment: Ohh i see, but when i put int() before NumOfMonth it is telling me now that int is not subscriptable?

Comment: @Emily: yes, but then you have your syntax backwards. `<object>[...]` will treat the object to the left of the brackets as the container, and what you look up in that container has to go in-between the brackets.

Comment: @Emily: You are also using `[...]` subscription in places where you should use `(...)` *calls*. `int()` is a callable object, `int("42")` converts the string `"42"` to an integer with the value 42, because you called it and passed in that string.

Comment: if you want to get the month name based on a number, then you need to subscribe to MonthList, not the other way around. Are you sure you understand how arrays and lists work in Python?

Comment: @Emily: but `int["42"]` (square brackets) tells Python to treat `int` as a container (a mapping in this case), and to find the entry with the string value `"42"` in that. Since `int` objects can't be indexed you get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your help, must seem dead easy to you pro's! Just trying to get the hang of the topics :)

Answer (score 2):

Convert `NumOfMonth` to integer by `int(NumOfMonth)`

The line should be:

```
FinalMessage = float(MonthList[NumOfMonth]), float(InterestList[NumOfMonth]), float(TotalBalance)
```

Your main problem was that you were getting your list indices mixed up. You want `NumOfMonth` inside the `[]`, not outside. This happened for the `InterestList` and `TotalBalance` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
FinalMessage = float(NumOfMonth[MonthList]), float(Interest[MonthList]), float(TotalBalance[MonthList])
```

you are using `MonthList` as an index which is a list. Also note that `totalBalance` and `Interest` are `float` objects and not a list object or an iterable. This makes `Interest[NumOfMonth]` and `TotalBalance[MonthList]` invalid.

It should be

```
   FinalMessage = float(MonthList[int(NumOfMonth])), InterestList[int(NumOfMonth]), TotalBalance
```

Comment: actually i basically used your line as well, i just made a seperate field defining NumOfMonth as int(NumOfMonth), thank you so much for your help!!!